# Stop Google Sheets from following a cut and pasted cell referenced in another sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I've set up two sheets, one called "Planning" and another called "contact" names in planning are meant to automatically populate "contact" by using `=planning!A1`but when I cut and paste a cell from planning the reference in "contact" moves with the cell. I.e. If I cut and past the content from A1 to B2 in planning, by reference in contact goes from `=planning!A1` to `=planning!B2` automatically. I want it to stay on A1 so that when I put something new in A1 that's what shows up in contact.

Comment: `=planning!$A$1`

Comment: or maybe `=indirect("planning!$A$1")`

Comment: or instead of cut and paste, use copy, paste, then delete if you actually need the content of A1 removed

Answer (score 1):

## Answer #1. Change cell reference

I suggest locking the cell:

`='Sheet1'!$A$1`

Notes:

- Dollar $ before a letter locks column
- Dollar $ before a number locks row

Tips:

- To switch between cell references use [F4] key when you edit a
  formula
- There are also [mixed cell references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9).
- Many tips from [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) about cell references works in [google-spreadsheets](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets),
  see more [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-change-a-cell-reference-C7B8B95D-C594-4488-947E-C835903CEBAA).

## Answer #2. Use [`INDIRECT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)

The other good solution is to use an indirect function:

`=indirect("'Sheet1'!A1")`

Notes:

- The good thing about it is you may totally control the range you get
  inside indirect. It also may be a range of multiple cells.
- Bad news, when you change the name of a sheet, an indirect formula
  will break.

---

Reference: [the article about getting a cell](https://sheetswithmaxmakhrov.wordpress.com/2018/01/29/get-the-dynamic-range-in-sheets/)

Comment: Thanks.  $ was the first thing I tried and it doesn't change anything. I think Google is trying to be a little too user friendly.

Comment: $ works for me. When I copy `=$A$1` into other sheets, it remains the same. Could you please describe your actions, so one could reproduce the error. Note: you may edit your question adding more details.